# Installed nvim with Chocolatey can't seem to find nvim location

Tags: vim, path, windows-10, chocolatey, neovim

Good day to yo all, I started learning coding and Web Development a little bit ago, do i started using nvim a little over a week ago, i'm still learning how to use it properly and one of the things i wanted to do was configure a couple thing in .vimrc however it seems first i need to alter some stuff in init.vim. My main problem is i installed nvim with Chocolatey and have no bloody idea where to find init.vim.
If anyone has any idea or has had the same issue, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think init.vim will exist initially, you need to create it at `~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim`

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3700#issuecomment-157778920